# How to add legend to distribution plot with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, distribution

I want to plot a negative binomial distribution and a Poisson distribution to fit my real data, but I don't know how to plot a legend, who can help me with that, thanks a lot. My code and picture is as follows:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(a),color="red",lwd=2) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=rpois(50,1.57)),color="purple",lwd=2) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=rnbinom(100,size=0.2,mu=1.57)),color="blue",lwd=2) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,10)) + labs(x="count")
```

[image]

And my data was uploaded here:
https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DSHXKgMQm5CLBhiKjCc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add a legend is to map a variable to color. For example

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(a, color="data"),lwd=2) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=rpois(50,1.57), color="poisson"),,lwd=2) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=rnbinom(100,size=0.2,mu=1.57),color="binomial"),lwd=2) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,10)) + labs(x="count")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The  bracket after "binomial" may should add before the parameter "color".

Comment: @user4672728 i've fixed the typo